# Symbolic links, PATH and privilege escalation vulnerability

Tags: vulnerability, privilege-escalation, symlink

I am a bit inexperienced to this...

I am using this VM https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/the-wall-1,130/ for practicing and there is a step I don't understand. Here: https://research.g0blin.co.uk/thewall-vulnhub-writeup/

> After calling strings on the binary, I can see one path that is not
>   correctly limited to a static path - mail. A rather crude way of
>   finding the vulnerability, but effective.

So basically to get DavidGilmour's shell I need to create a symbolic link to /bin/sh in /tmp/mail and change the PATH variable. But I don't understand why that is done nor how it works. Can anyone explain me?

I know the PATH variable is where the executables are, kind of like in Windows, so when I write, for example, 'cat' or some other command in the command prompt it works and I don't have to write the whole path to cat (at least that's what I believe it does).

And why is the symbolic link saved to /tmp/mail? And why is a symbolic link even used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attacker is attempting to get a shell running as the `DavidGilmour` user. Based on their explorations, the decision is to try to exploit a vulnerability in the `shineon` binary because that binary is setuid to `DavidGilmour`:

```
$ ls -lah /usr/local/bin/shineon
-rwsr-s---  1 DavidGilmour  RichardWright   7.3K Oct 25 07:58 /usr/local/bin/shineon
```

Notice the `s` in the permissions. That indicates that when `shineon` is run, it will run as `DavidGilmour`. But as `shineon` is a program of limited functionality, it doesn't have a `start shell` command. Instead, the attacker looks at the functionality the shell provides:

```
1. Calendar
2. Who
3. Check Internet
4. Check Mail
5. Exit
```

and then looks at the strings inside the binary. The relevant strings are:

```
/usr/bin/cal
/usr/bin/who
/sbin/ping -c 3 www.google.com
mail
```

The attacker guesses that those are the command strings used to execute the functionality of the application: `Calendar` corresponds to `/usr/bin/cal`, etc... The attacker cleverly notices that `mail` doesn't have a full path. This means that the script will run the first `mail` command it finds in the `PATH`. So the attacker creates a command named `mail` in some random directory. They chose `/tmp`, but that choice is unimportant. The command is a symbolic link to `/bin/sh`. A symbolic link creates an alias between two files. In this case, when the operating system executes `/tmp/mail`, it will actually execute `/bin/sh`. They could have copied `/bin/sh` to `/tmp/mail` as well, but why bother. Copying takes time and uses disk space. Symbolic linking is equally effective and faster.

The final step is to set the `PATH` environment variable to begin with `/tmp` so that when the OS goes to execute the `mail` command, it will find `/tmp/mail`. And, being that this is just a symbolic link to `/bin/sh`, it will execute `/bin/sh` as `DavidGilmour` (remember that the program is setuid so it always runs as `DavidGilmour`).

Goal achieved!